# Layout issues when running multiple jQuery effects

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, jquery-effects

I am having layout issues when running multiple jQuery effects. I am trying to move a div down by 100px to make room for a second div to appear in. My main div is moving down by 100px but then jumping a further 100px to accommodate the space needed for the 100px high  second div.  My jQuery  code is as follows;

```
$(function() {
    function runMenuEffect() {
        $( "#main-bottom-area" ).animate({top:"100px"}, 1000);
        $( ".slide-area" ).delay(1000).show( "drop", 1300 );
        $( ".maincontent-right-nav" ).delay(1500).hide( "fade", 1500 );
        $( "#main-bottom-area" ).delay(1500).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 1000);
    };
    $( "#sub-show-more" ).click(function() {
       runMenuEffect();
       return false;
    });
    $( ".slide-area" ).hide();
});
```

I thought this may be a css issue so tried to animate the box using top (with main box using position: relative;), margin-top and padding top.

CSS;

```
#main-bottom-area {
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
}

.slide-area {
    min-height:100px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: -9999px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -9999px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 9999px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 9999px;
}
```

Comment: Use `margin-top` or even better positioning and the `top` attribute. `Padding` adds height inside the element.

Comment: CSS would be delightful

Comment: Added css to question and also changed .animate to use top.

Comment: in the animation you can just chain the first and last lines together. Then you are not selecting twice.